# using a loop in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

i am trying to write a procedure that inserts rows into a temp table. the basis of the table is an insurance policy table listing the amount of the premium earned over the life of the policys. the original data consists of the trans_date (date sold) and the policy_start and policy_end dates. i.e. if the policy is 12 months long, we give each month 1/12 of the premium collected.

so something like

```
while trans_month < policy_end month

insert to tblUEPtmp
select dateadd(mm, 1, trans_date), earned_premium from tblpolicys

set trans_date = dateadd(mm, 1, trans_date)
```

(i know this is rubbush code but i completely baffled at the moment)

My problem is that i need to create the extra 11 rows of data and modify the transaction date to add 1 month each time until the modified transaction date = policy_end date.

i've researched using a CTE, but while loops aren't posible within a CTE..

is this something a multistatement table function could do?

Many thanks.

Comment: can We Have Little Explanation of what you doing.Thank you

Comment: trying to insert created rows that proportionally divides an original premium into the number of months between policy_start and policy_end so that i can sum up how much premium has been earned in any one month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can defo do this with a CTE, for example this little snippet will demonstrate how to do recursion using dates:

```
declare @start DATETIME = '2012-02-01'
declare @end DATETIME = '2013-02-01'
;with cte (date)
AS
(
    SELECT @start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(mm,1,cte.date)
    FROM cte WHERE DATEADD(mm,1,cte.date)<@end
)
select * from cte
```

That will generate a list of dates between `@start` & `@end` with month gaps.

You can

1. Use your real tables in place of the dummy dates
2. Perform an `insert into...select ... from cte` to insert your required data

If you can provide more detail about your table schema, I can probably help out with a more concrete example.

Comment: will this only work if i pass it one row at a time? what about passing it a query?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
set @trans_date = ...
while @trans_date < @policy_end
begin
    insert to tblUEPtmp 
      select trans_date, earned_premium
      from tblpolicys
      where {whatever}
    set @trans_date = dateadd(mm, 1, @trans_date)
end
```